# Unity 2D выделение объектов и взаимодействие с ними

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно сделать выделение юнитов как в стратегии только для 2D.Еще нужно для выделенных юнитов по клику выполнять методА(движение на координаты клика).

Само движение по клику я сделал, но двигаются все юниты.
Понимаю, что код большой и не на один скрипт, но подскажите в каком направление двигаться, потому что все туториалы направлены на 3D, мне это не подходит.

Comment: Да в общем то все то же самое что и с 3D, только поменяйте все коллайдеры с 3D на их аналоги 2D и будет вам счастие.

Comment: Вам нужно добавить состояние IsSelected = True || False в зависимости от состояния они должны двигаться этту проверку ставите перед вызовом метода движения